# JSON string or real JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I need to use some JSON data from external local file.

For me, the easiest way to do that is to make a string of JSON text and turn it into javascript object, like that:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="teachers.json"></script>

 <script>
    var data = JSON.parse(p);
    alert(data[0].name);
 </script>
```

and JSON file:

```
var p = `[
    {
        "name" : "Anna", 
        "age" : "45"
    },

    {
        "name" : "Bill", 
        "age" : "52"
    }
]`;
```

But I'd like to work with real JSON like 
`myObj = { "name":"John", "age":"31"};`

How can I use json from external local file without using jQuery?

Comment: JSON is just a string format so your title doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You have a `var` in a JSON file?

Comment: That is not a JSON file. That is a JavaScript file where you define a string containing JSON.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to put JSON in the file, just assign an ordinary object or array literal:

```
var p = [
    {
        "name" : "Anna", 
        "age" : "45"
    },

    {
        "name" : "Bill", 
        "age" : "52"
    }
];
```

Then you can just do:

```
var data = p;
```

in the main page.

BTW, you should call the file `teachers.js`. A `.json` file should just contain the JSON data by itself, not Javascript code to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

JSON to string:

```
JSON.stringify({ "name":"John", "age":"31"})
```

JSON from string:
JSON.parse(p);

You can save string in external local file.